# Edit src of img with codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to update the src attribute of `<img>` tags so that the user can insert images to the code from our asset manager.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div>
   <img src="some_image_already_defined.jpg" alt="Some Image" />
</div>
```

So if the user places the cursor to any position inside the img tag, I'll replace "some_image_already_defined.jpg" with the new image user selected.

The simplified version of code is smt. like that:

```
var image_path = 'some_new_image.jpg';
$('#insert-image').click(function() {
    var cur = codeMirrorHtml.getCursor();
    var token = codeMirrorHtml.getTokenAt(cur);
    var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(codeMirrorHtml.getMode(), token.state);

    if (inner.state.tagName == 'img') {
        var srcPosition = findTheSrcAttributePosition(); // How do I do this?
        codeMirrorHtml.setSelection(srcPosition.anchor, srcPosition.head);
        codeMirrorHtml.replaceSelection('src="' + image_path + '"');
    }
});
```

So I want to traverse the token somehow but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Get the current line number with [`getCursor`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getCursor):

```js
var line = editor.getCursor().line;
```

### Step 2

Get the contents of the current line using [`getLine`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getLine):

```js
var lineTxt = editor.getLine(line);
```

### Step 3

Find the `<img` tag. This is just a string search and it's up to you:

```js
var imgTagStartIdx = lineTxt.indexOf("<img");
```